# Programming Z-Tree Experiments

Tags: ztree

I'm using Z-Tree to program some public goods and prisoner's dilemma experiments. One annoying problem I'm facing is how to make fonts larger on a lot of the text that shows up in the Z-Leaves. I've done RTF wherever possible, but fonts in the HEADER and ENDOWMENT (i.e. 20 tokens) remain tiny because RTF can't be applied with "!radio". Please help!

Answer (score 1):

RTF can be applied with !radio:

```
!radio: 0 = "{\rtf \fs18 A }"; 1 = "{\rtf \fs18 B }";
```